# Store accessToken in iOS keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I'm looking for the simples way to store/load an accessToken and refreshToken in the iOS Keychain.

So far I've come to this:

```
    enum Key: String {
        case accessToken = "some.keys.accessToken"
        case refreshToken = "some.keys.refreshToken"
    
        fileprivate var tag: Data {
            rawValue.data(using: .utf8)!
        }
    }

    enum KeychainError: Error {
        case storeFailed
        case loadFailed
    }
    
    func store(key: Key, value: String) throws {
        let addQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: key.tag,
            kSecValueRef as String: value
        ]
        let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            print("Store key: '\(key.rawValue)' in Keychain failed with status: \(status.description)")
            throw KeychainError.storeFailed
        }
    }
    
    func load(key: Key) throws -> String? {
        let getQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: key.tag,
            kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            kSecReturnRef as String: true
        ]
        
        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &item)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else { 
            print("Load key: '\(key.rawValue)' in Keychain failed with status: \(status.description)")
            throw KeychainError.loadFailed 
        }
        return item as? String
    }
```

But this fail with messages:

When running `store`:

> Store key: 'some.keys.accessToken' in Keychain failed with status: -50

When running `load`:

> Load key: 'some.keys.accessToken' in Keychain failed with status: -25300

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since `SecItemAdd` and `SecItemCopyMatching` return `OSStatus`, their error codes are defined in `MacErrors.h`. `-50` is defined as `.paramErr`.  This seems to be the main problem.  `-25300 ` is `errKCItemNotFound` which is not surprising if the item were never stored in the first place.  I don't have the answer at the moment, but something must be wrong with `addQuery`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are making a query correctly.

Answer (score 8):

As per recommendations of Apple, you should use a `kSecClassGenericPassword` class to store arbitrary data, i.e. tokens, securely. To do that properly, you'll need a `String` identifier to store under the `kSecAttrAccount` key and a `Data` representation of the secure value to store under the `kSecValueData` key. You can easily transform your string value to `Data` by doing the following (assuming the token contains UTF8 data).

```swift
tokenString.data(using: .utf8)
// or
Data(tokenString.utf8)
```

First some nice to haves.

```swift
/// Errors that can be thrown when the Keychain is queried.
enum KeychainError: LocalizedError {
    /// The requested item was not found in the Keychain.
    case itemNotFound
    /// Attempted to save an item that already exists.
    /// Update the item instead.
    case duplicateItem
    /// The operation resulted in an unexpected status.
    case unexpectedStatus(OSStatus)
}

/// A service that can be used to group the tokens
/// as the kSecAttrAccount should be unique.
let service = "com.bundle.stuff.token-service"
```

Inserting a token into the Keychain.

```swift
func insertToken(_ token: Data, identifier: String, service: String = service) throws {
    let attributes = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService: service,
        kSecAttrAccount: identifier,
        kSecValueData: token
    ] as CFDictionary

    let status = SecItemAdd(attributes, nil)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
            throw KeychainError.duplicateItem
        }
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }
}
```

The retrieval will be done as follows.

```swift
func getToken(identifier: String, service: String = service) throws -> String {
    let query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService: service,
        kSecAttrAccount: identifier,
        kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne,
        kSecReturnData: true
    ] as CFDictionary

    var result: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)

    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        if status == errSecItemNotFound {
            // Technically could make the return optional and return nil here
            // depending on how you like this to be taken care of
            throw KeychainError.itemNotFound
        }
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }
    // Lots of bang operators here, due to the nature of Keychain functionality.
    // You could work with more guards/if let or others.
    return String(data: result as! Data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

Note that a generic password has certain specifications, as mentioned before, and I guess the most important one, is that the `kSecAttrAccount` flag must be unique for each token you store. You cannot store access token A and access token B for the same identifier. This will cause the `.duplicateItem` error to trigger.

I'd also like to point out that the [OSStatus website](https://osstatus.com) is very useful for getting more info about your error code. Besides the website there is also the `SecCopyErrorMessageString(OSStatus, UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)` function that can get you more information about your error code.

Now that technically answers your question, but below I've added some more nice to haves. Update updates a token value for an **existing** item, make sure the item exists before calling update!. Upsert inserts a token when it doesn't already exist, if it does, it will update the token value. Delete will remove the token value from the Keychain.

```swift
func updateToken(_ token: Data, identifier: String, service: String = service) throws {
    let query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService: service,
        kSecAttrAccount: identifier
    ] as CFDictionary

    let attributes = [
        kSecValueData: token
    ] as CFDictionary

    let status = SecItemUpdate(query, attributes)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        if status == errSecItemNotFound {
            throw KeychainError.itemNotFound
        }
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }
}

func upsertToken(_ token: Data, identifier: String, service: String = service) throws {
    do {
        _ = try getToken(identifier: identifier, service: service)
        try updateToken(token, identifier: identifier, service: service)
    } catch KeychainError.itemNotFound {
        try insertToken(token, identifier: identifier, service: service)
    }
}

func deleteToken(identifier: String, service: String = service) throws {
    let query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
        kSecAttrService: service,
        kSecAttrAccount: identifier
    ] as CFDictionary

    let status = SecItemDelete(query)
    guard status == errSecSuccess || status == errSecItemNotFound else {
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedStatus(status)
    }
}
```

Comment: "The kSecAttrAccount flag must be unique for each token you store." If I'm not mistaken, it is the *combination* of kSecAttrAccount and kSecAttrService which must be unique (which makes semantic sense - you can have the same account name for multiple services and vice versa).

Comment: what is kSecAttrService and is it is mandatory ?

Comment: @AhmadLabeeb [these are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattrservice); a service associated with the item. The value is, if I recall correctly, an optional `CFString` or `String` and not mandatory

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following edits, marked with comments:

```
   enum KeychainError: Error {
        case storeFailed
        case loadFailed
   }
        
   func store(key: Key, value: String) throws {
        let addQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: key.tag,
    // use kSecValueData, converting your String to Data
            kSecValueData as Data: value.data(using: .utf8)
        ]
        let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
        guard status == errSecSuccess else {
            print("Store key: '\(key.rawValue)' in Keychain failed with status: \(status.description)")
            throw KeychainError.storeFailed
        }
   }
        
   func load(key: Key) throws -> String? {
       let getQuery: [String: Any] = [
            kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
            kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: key.tag,

    // remove kSecAttrKeyType and add kSecReturnData 
            kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue
       ]
        
    // this is different    
       var item: AnyObject?
       let status: OSStatus = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to:&item)
       { (result: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?) -> OSStatus in
          return SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, result)
       }

       guard status == errSecSuccess else { 
          print("Load key: '\(key.rawValue)' in Keychain failed with status: \(status.description)")
          throw KeychainError.loadFailed 
       }
    // convert Data to String
       guard let itemData = item as? Data else { throw KeychainError.loadFailed }
       return String(decoding: itemData, as: UTF8.self)
    }
```

how does this change the behavior?

A couple comments:

- I'm not sure why you're using `kSecAttrKeyType` property to store a
  String
- I'm unsure of the use of `kSecValueRef` vs. `kSecValueData`,    only
  making this suggestion based on what has worked for me

Hope this helps!?

Comment: Seems to me that I'm able to store and load with you suggestions.. when checking `item != nil`, I see the item is not `nil`, but `String(decoding: item, as: UTF8.self)` is giving me a build error: _Initializer 'init(decoding:as:)' requires that 'AnyObject?' conform to 'Collection'_, so can't validate..

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to properly cast `item` to a `Data` ... sounds like we're close!